# Trying to position a table using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm creating a pdf roster using prawn in ruby on rails. I'm going to have about 100 rows in my table and it doesn't fit on one page when vertical. What I want to do is have the table wrap around once it reaches the bottom of the page, and start new rows to the right of the previous rows. I have the following code so far, which (depending on the options selected for the roster pdf) produces one long table that fits on six pages.

```
user_list.in_groups_of(26,false) do |ul| #26 reaches the bottom of the page 
    ul.each do |u|
    row = Array(u.first_name + " " + u.last_name ) #Individual Row
      columns.to_i.times do |c|
        row << "     " #Optional columns being added
      end
    data << row #Individual row being added to the table data
    end
  table(data,:row_colors => ["E0E0E0", "FFFFFF"])
  data = Array.new
end
```

I tried doing a bounding box but I couldn't get it to work. Is there some kind of positioning command I could add, and then increment it every time it grabs the next group of 26 people?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using column_box to get this desired layout. My end code now looks like

```
    column_box([0, cursor], :columns => 5, :width => bounds.width) do
     user_list.each do |u|
      row = Array(u.first_name + " " + u.last_name ) 
        columns.to_i.times do |c|
         row << "     "
        end #END OF COLUMN LOOP
      data << row 
     end #END OF USERLIST LOOP
     table(data,:row_colors => ["E0E0E0", "FFFFFF"],:width => 160 + (columns.to_i-1) * 30)
    end #END OF COLUMN_BOX
```

More information on column_box can be found [here](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-column_box).